# legend color are not proper showing in axlsx stacked bar chart

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, axlsx, caxlsx

I'm working on the xlsx chart generation and for that using axlsx gem.I'm looking for the option to show correct **legend (label)** color. right now, not showing correct color in stacked Bar chart. Please check the label color on right side option in the image.[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: minimal reproducible code helps.  can you edit your question with what you have so far?